# having issue opening modal on javascript and php

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

i am facing some kind of issue here in my javascript i think, it was working to open a small windows, but i don't know how it's not working now. here's below my javascript code ad my php and html codes

```
<?php
require_once '../core/init.php';
$id = $_POST['id'];
if(is_numeric($id) && $id > 0 && $id == round($id, 0)){
 $id = $_POST['id'];

} else {
 exit;
}
$id = (int)$id;
$sql = "SELECT * FROM products WHERE id = '$id'";
$result = $db->query($sql);
$product = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);
$brand_id = $product['brand'];
$sql = "SELECT brand FROM brand WHERE id = '$brand_id'";
$brand_query = $db->query($sql);
$brand = mysqli_fetch_assoc($brand_query);
$sizestring = $product['sizes'];
$size_array = explode(',', $sizestring);
?>

<!-- Details Modal -->
<?php ob_start(); ?>
<div class="modal fade details-1" id="details-modal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="details-1" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg">
        <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
            <button class="close" type="button" onclick="closemodal()" aria-label="close">
                <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
            </button>
            <h4 class="modal-title text-center"><?php echo $product['title']; ?></h4>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
            <div class="container-fluid">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-sm-6">
                        <div class="center-block">
                            <img src="<?php echo $product['image']; ?>" alt="<?php echo $product['title']; ?>" class="details img-responsive">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-sm-6">
                        <h4>Details</h4>
                        <p><?php echo $product['description']; ?></p>
                        <hr>
                        <p>Price: $<?php echo $product['price']; ?></p>
                        <p>Brand: <?php echo $brand['brand']; ?></p>
                        <form action="add_cart.php" method="post">
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <div clss="col-xs-3">
                                    <label for="quantity">Quantity:</label>
                                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="quantity" name="quantity">
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label for="size">Size:</label>
                                <select name="size" id="size" class="form-control">
                                    <option value=""></option>
                                    <?php foreach($size_array as $string) {
                                        $string_array = explode(':', $string);
                                        $size = $string_array[0];
                                        $quantity = $string_array[1];
                                        echo '<option value="'.$size.'">'.$size.' ('.$quantity.' Available)</option>';
                                        } ?>
                                </select>
                            </div>
                        </form>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
            <button class="btn btn-default" onclick="closemodal()">Close</button>
            <button class="btn btn-warning" type="submit"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-shopping-cart"></span>Add To Cart</button>
        </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<script>
function closemodal(){
jQuery ('#details-modal').modal('hide');
setTimeout(function(){
    jQuery('#details-modal').remove();
    jQuery('.modal-backdrop').remove();
    },500);
}
</script>
<?php echo ob_get_clean(); ?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After looking at your `var_dump($product);` result:

```
array(10) {
    ["id"]=> string(1) "1"
    ["title"]=> string(12) "Levi's Jeans"
    ["price"]=> string(5) "29.99"
    ["list_price"]=> string(5) "39.99"
    ["band"]=> string(1) "1"
    ["categories"]=> string(1) "6"
    ["image"]=> string(24) "images/products/men4.png"
    ["description"]=> string(16) "Description here"
    ["featured"]=> string(1) "1"
    ["sizes"]=> string(14) "28:3,32:2,36:5"
}
```

It's obvious that you do not have a field named 'brand`in your`products` table.

The nearest field name to `brand` is `band` which I think is a typo. So if you change this line of your code:

```
`$brand_id = $product['brand'];`
```

To this

```
`$brand_id = $product['band'];`
```

Then you will solve the error

> Notice: Undefined index: brand

And in this query `$sql = "SELECT * FROM products WHERE id = '$id'";` since `$id` is `integer`, there is no need to enclose it in single quotes and you can have your query like this:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM products WHERE id = $id";
```

Also looking at your queries, you have two queries which you can combine them to a single query using a simple `join`

You have `"SELECT * FROM products WHERE id = '$id'" and "SELECT brand FROM brand WHERE id = '$brand_id'"

In table `products`, the field `band` is foreign key to table `brand` field `id` So you can simply write this query:

```
$sql = "SELECT products.*, brand.brand FROM products left join brand on products.band = brand.id WHERE products.id = $id";
```

So your `php` section at the top of your `detailsmodal.php` file will become like this:

```
<?php
require_once '../core/init.php';
$id = $_POST['id'];
if(is_numeric($id) && $id > 0 && $id == round($id, 0)){
 $id = $_POST['id'];
} else {
 exit;
}
$id = (int)$id;

$sql = "SELECT products.*, brand.brand FROM products left join brand on products.band = brand.id WHERE products.id = $id";
$result = $db->query($sql);
$product = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);
$sizestring = $product['sizes'];
$size_array = explode(',', $sizestring);
?>
```

and then only at this line of your `html`:

```
<p>Brand: <?php echo $brand['brand']; ?></p>
```

You have to change it to

```
<p>Brand: <?php echo $product['brand']; ?></p>
```

**Note:** Since you are using `mysqli`, It's highly advised to use [prepared statements](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.prepare.php) instead of just putting your variable directly in your query